# How to make a function takes a parameter of different types in Javascript and returns a date in the format "dd.mm.yy"?

Tags: javascript

My example, run in visual studio code:
Fail  Expected: "02.10.20"
Received: "10/02/20"

```
export const formatDate = (...date) => {
    date = date.flat();
    if(typeof date[0] === 'string') date = [Date.parse(...date)];
    date = new Date(...date);
   return (new Intl.DateTimeFormat("en-US", {
            day: "2-digit" ,
           month: "2-digit",
            year: "2-digit"
        })).format(date)
    }
```

tests:

```
 expect(formatDate('2020-10-02')).toEqual('02.10.20');
expect(formatDate(1234567890000)).toEqual('14.02.09');
expect(formatDate([2020, 0, 1])).toEqual('01.01.20');
expect(formatDate(new Date(2014, 0, 1))).toEqual('01.01.14');
```

Comment: Maybe you want to change it to sth different than `en-US`? `de-DE` Would work in your case.

Comment: I tried changing the format, but that didn't help me, Fail  on first test :Expected: "02.10.20" Received: "10/02/20"     https://ibb.co/jM4wBCT

Comment: What is you target locale? Where does the user come from that is perceiving this formatted date?

Comment: format is needed, suitable for passing tests, i.e. I do not know what format

Answer (score 0):

You can simply switch `en-US` to sth like `de-DE`

```js
const formatDate = (...date) => {
    date = date.flat();
    if (typeof date[0] === 'string') date = [Date.parse(...date)];
    date = new Date(...date);
    return (new Intl.DateTimeFormat('de-DE', {
        day: '2-digit',
        month: '2-digit',
        year: '2-digit',
    })).format(date);
};

console.log(formatDate('2020-10-02') === '02.10.20');
console.log(formatDate(1234567890000) === '14.02.09');
console.log(formatDate([2020, 0, 1]) === '01.01.20');
console.log(formatDate(new Date(2014, 0, 1)) === '01.01.14');
```